# Passing a noncopyable class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am reading a book and the author has a noncopyable class which ends up as a member variable of another class. It stuck out to me, because of the way the author did it and because he preferred a pointer to a reference. Let me give an example.

```
class Foo;         // noncopyable
class WrapperFoo
{
public:
    explicit    WrapperFoo(Foo& x)
                : mFoo(&x)
                {}

    Foo*    mFoo;
};
```

What the author did that surprised me was he passed the Foo object by reference and then he takes the address of the Foo object and contructs the mFoo pointer. Why start with a reference to end with a pointer?

```
class Foo;         // noncopyable
class WrapperFoo
{
public:

    explicit    WrapperFoo(Integer* x)
                : mFoo(x)
                {}

    Integer*    mFoo;
};
```

If I wanted a pointer this seems more straightforward (and identical). I do understand this may just be preference.

```
class Foo;         // noncopyable
class WrapperFoo
{
public:
    explicit    WrapperFoo(Integer& x)
                : mFoo(x)
                {}

    Integer&    mFoo;
};
```

Further, I've read to prefer references to pointers, so why not this?

I believe the three examples are accomplishing the same task.  Am I missing something?  Why might the author prefer pointers to references in this example?  Finally, is there a name for this usage?

Comment: Once you have a reference data member, your class becomes non-assignable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having references as data members is more often than not unpleasant as they have to be initialized in the initializer list (at object creation time, this has some implications such as the type being non-assignable). It's generally a better idea just to keep a pointer - although if it's an owning pointer, then might as well use the std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr.

As to why he used the take by reference and then he took the address, well, it was to avoid the reference as a data member AND keep the interface to the call simple (so that arg instead of &arg can be used.)

Answer (score 3):

Passing the reference prevents you from passing a NULL pointer to the Constructor. It guarantees that the object exists during creation.

Answer (score 1):

My guess about authors intentions would be that taking reference instead of pointer means that we are guaranteed at object creation time that the address contains valid object. A storage of pointer makes object copyable and, if needed, rebindable.

Though none of the approaches guarantees that passed object is stays valid after object creation.